Uvicorn/FastAPI randomly takes several seconds to receive messages
I have a web app that runs an HTML page with JavaScript WebSockets on the frontend, and a FastAPI/Uvicorn backend. Now the JS connects to the backend and sends a message every second. On reception of that message the backend sends the current state of a dataset.
The backend part:
@app.websocket("/tourenplan/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    global counter
    global tour_result
    global last_check
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        try:
            print("Received_Start", datetime.now())
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            print("Received", datetime.now())
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            loop.run_in_executor(executor, tourabruf.handle_data, data)
            #tourabruf.handle_data(data)
            asyncio.create_task(update_tour_result())
            await websocket.send_json(tour_result)
            print("Received_Done", datetime.now())
        except ConnectionClosedError:
            print('Client left early.')
            break
        except starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect:
            print('Client left early.')
            break
        except ConnectionClosedOK:
            print('Connection closed OK exception.')
            break

    counter += 1

The frontend part:
function setupSocket()
{
    if (socket != null)
        socket.close()
    socket = new WebSocket('{{ websocket_url }}');
    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log(new Date().getTime(), "RECV");
        last_contact = new Date().getTime();
        var updatedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        currentData = updatedData;
        updateView();
    };
};


setupSocket();
updateRow();
setInterval(function() {updateRow();}, 1000);

var recentConnectionAttempt = false;
function updateRow() {
    if(new Date().getTime() - last_contact > 5000)
    {
        document.getElementById('connectionstatus').textContent = 'Keine Verbindung zum Server';
        if (!recentConnectionAttempt)
        {
            recentConnectionAttempt = true;
            setupSocket();
        }
        else recentConnectionAttempt = false;
    }

    if (socket.readyState === socket.OPEN)
    {
        document.getElementById('connectionstatus').textContent = 'Mit Server verbunden';
        console.log(new Date().getTime(), "SEND");
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(send_queue));
        send_queue = [];
    }
}

This mostly works, but every now and then, sometimes several times a minute, the backend does not receive the messages on the WebSocket and they pile up for several seconds until they are all received and responded to at once.
I can see with WireShark that the messages are sent by the frontend and ACK'd by the backend socket (it's all on localhost), but in the backend program it still waits on websocket.receive_text().
Now I'm a little stuck as to what causes this issue here, because again, I am on localhost, the server does not have to do anything else (the calls in the backend are done asynchronically by AsyncIO so nothing should stall there) and I can see the frontend sending its messages and the backend socket acknowledging them without showing it in my program.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this or get to the bottom of the issue? It would be okay if the data feed stops for a few seconds every hour or so, but several times a minute is way too much.

Have you tried running your socket function with line_profiler or attaching to the process with strace to see what's happening? Does your handle_data take a long time?

Complete working examples could be found here here and here, as well as here,  here and here

Make sure you don't have any blocking code in your update_tour_result
